# Download large number PHAssets from iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, phasset

I am working on an app that backs up a user's photo library to a flash drive. The issue I am running into is with photos that are stored in iCloud.

When the user has the 'Optimize Storage' option enabled, there can be thousands of photos stored in iCloud. When using requestImageForAsset or requestImageDataForAsset, if the photo is not stored on the phone, it gets downloaded back the user's photo library. This means thousands of photos, which can be several GB of data, are being loaded back onto the users device. For some users who are low on storage, it is causing the app to not function correctly.

Is there any way to download a full resolution PHAsset that is stored in the iCloud without it being copied to the Photos app?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. The phasset im getting in photoLibraryDidChange: method are not the same i think. requesting image returns nil.